# Converting nested summation to R type matrix multiplication

Tags: r, nested, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement a nested summation in R. The for loop implementation is:

```
 sum = 0
  for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
      for(k in 1:n){
        sum = sum + w[i,j]*w[j,k]
      }
    }
  }
```

where `w` is a symmetric square matrix and `n` is the number of rows (or columns).
[Please see the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWM02.png) I am trying to implement. (SO did not allow me to write Latex nor add the image here.)

The nested for loops above takes forever. How do I implement this efficiently the R way?

Comment: Can you provide an example and the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sum2 <- sum(w %*% w)

all.equal(Sum, Sum2)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

We used for comparison:

```
# input
set.seed(123)
n <- 5
w <- matrix(rnorm(n^2), n)

# from question
Sum = 0
  for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
      for(k in 1:n){
        Sum = Sum + w[i,j]*w[j,k]
      }
    }
  }
```